# Date Views is not Working In my views

Tags: views

I have created a views to listing fixtures but i want date filter exposed to users to select date, to filter fixtures respect to that value. I[image] have created a date filter in filter criteria section but it shows only label not showing popup calendar..how can i make it work?Thanks in Advance

Comment: Try switching to the default Drupal theme to see if works there. If it does works then there is some CSS or Javascript that might be hiding it.